# How to retrieve the SQL query string of an F# query expression via System.Data.SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, f#, query-expressions

I'm using the [System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org) and I'm trying to retrieve the SQL string that is generated by the query expression below. The query executes correctly, but the SQL string is `SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]`.

It seems that `GetCommand().CommandText` is not supported, but if so, how else is it possible to access the generated SQL string?

```ml
[<Test>]
member this.showSQL() =
    let connectionString = sprintf @"Data Source=%s;UTF8Encoding=True;Version=3" dbFilename
    let connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
    use dc = new DataContext(connection)

    let channelMap = dc.GetTable<ChannelData>()

    let map = query {
        for row in channelMap do
        where (row.ChannelId = 1)
        select (row.ChannelId, row.Data0, row.State) }

    let cmd = dc.GetCommand(map).CommandText;
    printf "SQL: %s" cmd
```

Comment: I notice that the official examples execute the query before reading `CommandText`.

Comment: Good idea, tried that, same result.

Answer (score -1):

The SQLiteCommand object has the associated CommandText property working as intended.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sql = "select * from foo";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, null);

        Console.WriteLine(command.CommandText);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Perhaps you can rework your code to utilize it.

Comment: The code above prints what was put into `SQLiteCommand` before. But what I needed was a way to convert the F# query expression to an SQL string for debugging purposes. Going back to the F# code, the `dc.GetCommand(map)` line actually returns an `SQLiteCommand` instance, but without the SQL I would expect. My suspicion is that `SQLiteCommand` uses SQLite's C API instead of going through the SQL conversion. May be someone can confirm that.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying.  I suppose it is possible, in which case they may have overridden the ToString command.

What does dc.GetCommand(map).CommandText.ToString() produce?

Comment: It produces the same result, because `CommandText` is already a string.